# Custom Buttons in Python ctypes MessageBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, messagebox

I need a python messagebox with custom buttons. [image: This is an Edited Pic]

I need something like this. I need it to return the button clicked. Like If I clicked 'A' it would return 'A'

I know about tkinter but I want to use this with pygame and can't get it to work.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619418/how-to-create-a-custom-messagebox-using-tkinter-in-python-with-changing-message) Q help you out

Comment: or you could actually design a window like this in tkinter

Comment: I tried to make it myself with tkinter but couldn't make it return the clicked button

Comment: Ive added an answer, do let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I made with tkinter, not the perfect messagebox, but why not?

For the theme used you have to install it first, like:

```
pip install ttkthemes
```

Then the code

```
# imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tktheme
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import messagebox

# making new themed window
root = tktheme.ThemedTk()
root.title('Take selection')
root.get_themes()
root.set_theme('vista')

# message to be shown by the box
message = 'Here is a custom messagebox.'

# defining functions
def click1():
    root.destroy()
    return 'A'


def click2():
    root.destroy()
    return 'B'


def click3():
    root.destroy()
    return 'C'


# creating white frame
frame1 = Frame(height=139, width=440, bg='white')
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

# creating gray frame
frame2 = ttk.Frame(height=50, width=440)
frame2.grid(row=1, column=0)

# importing the image, any image can be used(for the question mark)
dir = Image.open('Blue_question.png')
dir = dir.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img_prof = ImageTk.PhotoImage(dir)
img_label = Label(root, image=img_prof, bg='white')
img_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25)

# defining main label
cust_messagebox = Label(root, text=message, font=('Arial', 10), bg='white')
cust_messagebox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=(95, 0))

# defining buttons
button1 = ttk.Button(root, text='A', command=click1)
button1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=30, ipadx=10)

button2 = ttk.Button(root, text='B', command=click2)
button2.grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=10)

button3 = ttk.Button(root, text='C', command=click3)
button3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E, padx=(0, 30), ipadx=10)

# keeping the app alive
root.mainloop()
```

With bigger messages you might want to increase the width of the frames and the play with the padding of the widgets too.

If any doubts or errors, do let me know.

Cheers

Comment: The return statements are pointless in functions called from a button.

Comment: IKR, OP said he wanted it to return A, B and C. So i did as the OP asked

Comment: Thanks the design is perfect, I can mess with it myself to make it adapt to different messages and more buttons.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't actually return A, B, or C. Nowhere in the code can the OP use the value returned by the function because nothing receives the returned value.

Comment: Also I think instead, I will have you enter a function that you would like to run with the parameter of the button clicked, so I can handle it in any way I want

Comment: @Ultra also ,you can mess around with the code and store the value inside of a variable and use it else where, be sure to say `global variable_name` (which im not sure, but might work)