# How to change rocket icon in Tkinter showinfo message box on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using macOS Big Sur to code Python. I can't change the rocket icon in showinfo message box. How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: message box is given by the OS, tkinter just call them. You would need to write your own via `tk.Toplevel()` for instance.

Comment: How can I do it? Can you send an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a custom messagebox using Tkinter in Python with changing message and changing button state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619418/how-to-create-a-custom-messagebox-using-tkinter-in-python-with-changing-message)

Comment: Seems like not. It seems to be on WIndows

Comment: @HuyVuQuang did you even try? also have you ever made a window in `tkinter`? well make the same thing except using `Toplevel` (doesn't require `.mainloop()`) and adjust it for your needs

Comment: I am a newbie to Tkinter and have just learnt it for a week