# Tkinter get rid of the python icon in messagebox tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-button, tkmessagebox

How can I get rid of the Python (or `matplotlib`) icon when running this code? Even when I add `icon='info'`, I still get the rocket with the python logo. Please check the photo in reference.

```py
from tkinter import * import tkinter as tk from tkinter import messagebox as tm
        root=Tk() root.geometry("1200x1200") canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300) canvas1.pack() def ExitApplication():

    text=text= ' Our team thank you for your visit ! '
            
    MsgBox=tk.messagebox.askquestion('Exit the platform' , text, icon='info')
    if MsgBox=='yes':
        root.destroy()
    else:
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Return', 'You will now return to the application screen ', icon='info')

exit_button = Button(root, text="Exit ", command=ExitApplication) canvas1.create_window(200, 200, window=exit_button)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: I need to get rid of this logo please]

Answer (score 0):

`icon=info` is used for changing the icon inside message box.
[Answered here nicely.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815007/change-icon-for-tkinter-messagebox)

---

[Referring to this question and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68789319/14465779), one solution could be to **create your own custom messagebox** using `tk.Toplevel()`:

Here is an example of how you would be coding it. (You can further make it more efficient for multiple messageboxes):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
#from tkinter import messagebox as tm

root=Tk()
root.geometry("1200x1200")
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()
def ExitApplication():
    text = ' Our team thank you for your visit ! '
    
    MsgBox=Toplevel(root)
    MsgBox.title("Exit the platform")
    MsgBox.geometry(f"300x100+{root.winfo_x()}+{root.winfo_y()}")
    icon = PhotoImage(file="Any image file")#provide here the image file location
    MsgBox.iconphoto(True, icon)
     
    l1=Label(MsgBox, image="::tk::icons::question")
    l1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(7, 0), padx=(10, 30), sticky="e")
    l2=Label(MsgBox,text=text)
    l2.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=(7, 10), sticky="w")
 
    b1=Button(MsgBox,text="Yes",command=root.destroy,width = 10)
    b1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(2, 35), sticky="e")
    b2=Button(MsgBox,text="No",command=lambda:[MsgBox.destroy(), returnBack()],width = 10)
    b2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(2, 35), sticky="e")

def returnBack():
    pass
    #Similarly, create a custom messagebox using Toplevel() for showing the following info:
    #tk.messagebox.showinfo('Return', 'You will now return to the application screen ', icon='info')

exit_button = Button(root, text="Exit ", command=ExitApplication)
canvas1.create_window(200, 200, window=exit_button)

root.mainloop()
```

---

But if you are looking for a solution to **change the default icon with an .ico icon file**, for entire Tkinter windows including MessageBox [refer here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/change-icon-for-tkinter-messagebox/), just use `iconbitmap`:

```
import tkinter as tk


win = tk.Tk()
win.title("example")
win.iconbitmap(".ico file location")

win.mainloop()
```